# How to interpret Python output dtype='<U32'?

Tags: python, numpy

I am taking an online course, and the following supposedly demonstrates that "NumPy arrays: contain only one type":

```
In [19]: np.array([1.0, "is", True])
Out[19]:
array(['1.0', 'is', 'True'],
dtype='<U32')
```

At first, I thought that the output was a form of error message, but this is not confirmed by a web search.  In fact, I haven't come across an explanation....can anyone explain how to interpret the output?

**Afternote:** After reviewing the answers, the [`dtype` page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), and the [`numpy.array()` page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), it seems that `dtype='<U32'` would be more accurately described as `dtype('<U32')`. Is this correct?  I seems so to me, but I'm a newbie, and even the [`numpy.array()` page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) assigns a string to the `dtype` parameter rather than an actual `dtype` object.

Also, why does `'<U32'` specify a 32-character string when all of the elements are much shorter strings?

Comment: See [Numpy data type objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Comment: The course wants you to see that while the input list contains a float, a string and a boolean, the resulting array just has strings.  The float and boolean have converted to their string counterparts.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar and hpaulj.  I actually did not notice that the output was an array of strings until you pointed that out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is fully explained in the [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html):

> Several kinds of strings can be converted. Recognized strings can be prepended with `'>'` (big-endian), `'<'` (little-endian), or `'='` (hardware-native, the default), to specify the byte order.
>
> [...]
>
> The first character specifies the kind of data and the remaining characters specify the number of bytes per item, except for Unicode, where it is interpreted as the number of characters. The item size must correspond to an existing type, or an error will be raised. The supported kinds are
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> 'U'        Unicode string
> ```

So, a little-endian Unicode string of 32 characters.

Comment: Thanks, Amadan.  It's quite a detailed description.

Answer (score 9):

`dtype='<U32'` is a little-endian 32 character string.

The [documentation on dtypes](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) goes into more depth about each of the character.

`'U'  Unicode string`

`Several kinds of strings can be converted. Recognized strings can be prepended with '>' (big-endian), '<' (little-endian), or '=' (hardware-native, the default), to specify the byte order.`

Examples:

````
dt = np.dtype('f8')   # 64-bit floating-point number
dt = np.dtype('c16')  # 128-bit complex floating-point number
dt = np.dtype('a25')  # 25-length zero-terminated bytes
dt = np.dtype('U25')  # 25-character string```
````

Comment: I really appreciate the examples.  Frankly, I don't think I'm at a point where the cited documentation is meaningful.