# Is Python's dict_items() a constructor that is inaccessible to users?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I was learning Python dictionaries at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_items.asp):

```
car = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

x = car.items()

print(x)
```

I get:

```
dict_items([('brand', 'Ford'), ('model', 'Mustang'), ('year', 1964)])
```

The `dict_items` looks like a conversion function or class constructor, but it is not recognized at the command line:

```
>>> dict_items([('brand', 'Ford'), ('model', 'Mustang'), ('year', 1964)])

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'dict_items' is not defined
```

The most authoritative explanation I found is the Python documentation on [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), but it still doesn't say anything about what `dict_items` is.  Is it just a constructor that is not accessible to the public?

Comment: It's an `iterable` view that you you iterate over as shown https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: What you are seeing with `dict_items([('brand', 'Ford'), ('model', 'Mustang'), ('year', 1964)])` is the `repr`. So in your case `for key, value in x: print(key, value)` prints out the keys and values.

Comment: @Axe319: Thanks, I read about iterables on-and-off over the past year. It doesn't really help me identify what the word `dict_items` refers to. But your explanation of `repr` makes a lot of sense!  It might even explain a similar question I had about `dtype='<U32'` vs. `dtype('<U32')` in the *Afternote* of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944812/how-to-interpret-python-output-dtype-u32).  Would you mind posting this as the answer?

Comment: As an aside, "I was learning Python dictionaries at W3Schools" **don't**. W3Schools is notoriously bad. Just use the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and documentation.

Comment: @user36800 the *word* `dict_items` is just part of the printed representation of that object. A dict_items object is an instance of a class, `dict_items`. That class isn't exposed anywhere, and it isn't in the built-in namespace so `dict_items` will be a `NameError`, although, you can trivially retrieve it using `dict_items = type({}.items())`. Note sure what you dont' understand exactly... There are many classes which are part of the Python runtime which are not in the built-in namespace, this isn't strange or unusual.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Thanks for the pointer to the official tutorial.  I actually don't stop with W3Schools, it's whatever I find via Google. What I didn't understand about dict_item was that it is presented to the user as a function invocation, and I was wondering if that was the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`items()` is a method implemented on the `dict` object that returns a `iterable` dictionary view.

The main noticeable difference from this and an `iterator` from a users perspective is you can `iterate` over the view multiple times whereas an `iterator` gets consumed. And still maintain the memory savings, since as @ juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, it is only a wrapper around the underlying structure.

It's [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f37ebc61e9e0d13bcb1a2ddb7fc9723c04b6372/Objects/dictobject.c#L4873) seen here is implemented in C as `dict_items` which would explain the `repr`.

What can you do with this view? Well typically you see it used directly in a `for` loop such as:

```
for key, value in dct.items():
    print(key, value)
```

When iterated over it returns a key, value `tuple` for each `dict` entry which is typically unpacked into 2 variables as shown above.

You may also notice `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` which work in a similar fashion but for the keys and values individually.

Now onto the `__repr__`.
When you create a python object.

```
class MyClass:
    pass
foo = MyClass()
print(foo)
```

It gives a default representation of the object and its memory location.
Something like

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x0175F718>
```

This looks kind of ugly and isn't very informative.

You can override this behavior by defining a `__repr__` method returning what you want it to display.
Typically, this is the class name and the arguments it was called with.

So

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
         self.x = x
    def __repr__(self):
         return f'MyClass(x={self.x})'
foo = MyClass(3)
print(foo)
```

would return

```
MyClass(x=3)
```

Comment: It isn't "lazy evaluation". It's a *view*, which basically is just a wrapper over some other data structure, that lets you "view" the data without copying the underlying structure

Comment: Maybe lazy evaluation isn't the best term. I'll remove it.

Comment: Also, that [link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f37ebc61e9e0d13bcb1a2ddb7fc9723c04b6372/Objects/dictobject.c#L2321) is actually *not* the implementation of `dict.items`... taht seems to be the old implementation that returned a list of tuples... probably kept around for internal use. [This is the actual method directly](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f37ebc61e9e0d13bcb1a2ddb7fc9723c04b6372/Objects/dictobject.c#L4873) which just calls [this helper function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f37ebc61e9e0d13bcb1a2ddb7fc9723c04b6372/Objects/dictobject.c#L4211)

Comment: That helper method eventually makes an actual view object. [Here's the associated C structure that corresponds to the `dict_items` type](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f37ebc61e9e0d13bcb1a2ddb7fc9723c04b6372/Objects/dictobject.c#L4839) and it's associated methods.

Comment: Thank you, Axe319, for the deep explanation, and juanpa.arrivillaga, for suggesting improvements.